# Change Feature Type Details in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html, Section
"Feature Type Details (Vector)" lists a Layers Features including its Feature Type.

How can I edit these?

Comment: If you solve this problem, look at [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165181), please.

Answer (score 3):

How to edit the schema of FeatureType is documented in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html

As the document says there are limited possibilities to edit the schema:

> The GeoServer WFS supports a limited amount of schema output
>   customization. A custom schema may be useful for the following:
>
> ```
> Limiting the attributes which are exposed in the feature type schema
> Changing the types of attributes in the schema
> Changing the structure of the schema (for example, changing the base feature type)
> ```

The document does not tell clearly how to edit the schema but by following these steps and the documentation it should be quite easy:

Download the current schema of FeatureType with DescribeFeatureType request

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=topp%3Astates
```

When you get the schema to your browser show the source code of the page and save it as a text file. The file name must be "schema.xsd" and the full path fox example "topp:states" will be like

```
\geoserver-2.6.0\data_dir\workspaces\topp\states_shapefile\states\schema.xsd
```

Edit the schema.xsd file and save it. Go to the admin utility and from the Layer - Data page press the "Reload feature type" link.

If you want to change the names of attributes it is not possible this way. You must either edit the attribute names directly in your data (shapefile or table in the database) or if you use database, create a view where the attributes are renamed and publish the view with GeoServer

```
CREATE VIEW beautified AS SELECT geometry, long_ugly_attribute_name as neat_name,...
```

Comment: How can we add a property to an element? See [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165181), please.