# Custom DescribeFeatureType response in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, describe-feature-type

I'm using [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org) in my web application. I need custom `DescribeFeatureType` response. What this mean?
layer_a is a layer in Geoserver. It have `Feature Type Details` as follow:

[image]

`DiscribeFeatureType` request for this layer, return a response as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
              xmlns:opengeo="http://opengeo.org" 
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
              elementFormDefault="qualified" 
              targetNamespace="http://opengeo.org">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
              schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="WorldCountriesType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ObjectID" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FIPS_CNTRY" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SQKM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SQMI" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="COLORMAP" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="WorldCountries" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="opengeo:WorldCountriesType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I want to get more description for some fields. For example, for `SQKM` row, I want to get some extra description such as: `minValue`, `maxValue` and etc.

**Is it possible**? If yes, **HOW**?

**A suggestion**: We can put our data in column comment of table and then define a db datastore in geoserver. So we can response comment of table with `describeFeatureType`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited possibility to adjust the schema by using the schema mapping as described in http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.1/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html. However, the following edit did not change anything in DescribeFeatureType and maxLength does not appear in the schema of of the topp:states layer even the edited schema.xsd was accepted and I verified by removing some attributes from the schema that the file was really used.

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" maxLength="30"/>
```

There is also this open issue which suggests that what you want to do is not doable at the moment https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-5336.

However, the application schema extension is flexible and it might work for you but it is complex http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/index.html.